# PDF Adding Electronic Signature

Tags: pdf, itext, electronic-signature

We have an API for adding electronic signature to PDF documents. PDF documents signed by our API generally have the following structure:

```
/Type/Annot/
/Type/Sig/
/Type/Font/BaseFont/Helvetica
/Type/Font/BaseFont/ZapfDingbats
/Type/XObject/Subtype/Form
/Type/Page/
/Type/Catalog/
xref
0 1
0000000000 65535 f 
57 1
0000088682 00000 n 
221 7
0000088804 00000 n 
0000088450 00000 n 
0000054970 00000 n 
0000088289 00000 n 
0000054837 00000 n 
0000088111 00000 n 
0000088211 00000 n 
trailer
<</Size 228/Root 221 0 R/Info 222 0 R/ID [<e8f997fdc4d9ee619c59add6882586d8><d13406b4c1e0cb3de6c1e8dd21d6be13>]/Prev 50291>>
startxref
89038
%%EOF
```

Yet, when we analyzed other API outputs, we also saw structure as follows:

```
/Type/Sig
/Type/XObject/Subtype/Form
/Type/Metadata/Subtype/XML
/Type/Catalog
/Type/ObjStm/N 4
34 0 obj
<</Length 52/Filter/FlateDecode/Size 35/Root 8 0 R/Info 6 0 R/ID [<4dc91a1875a6d707aec203bb021c93a0><b6fc5ae423a75860537207ff441de268>]/W[1 2 2]/Type/XRef/Index[0 2 6 1 8 2 28 7]/Prev 116>>stream
xœc``øÿŸq‘-ãB9 ±Şš‰A™QÈ]Pá%AXŒ ‚‰¤ =› ñ
endstream
endobj
startxref
45383
%%EOF
```

We could not find any reference to this difference in the PDF Standarts document nor Adding e-Signature to PDF documents guidelines. Can you please give information on when to use which format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't know and understand the PDF specification, you shouldn't try to create your own API. Just use a recent version of iText and you'll be safe. **Do not use old versions of iText, because a large part of the signature functionality was deprecated in PDF 2.0.** For instance: all signatures created with iText versions prior to iText 5.4 are outdated. Check when your API was created. If it predates the PAdES standard, you should no longer use it. Go for ISO 32000-2 implementations (ISO 32000-2 was released in July 2017).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is totally unrelated to iText, and even unrelated to digital signatures.

Let's start with PDF's that end like this:

```
xref
0 1
0000000000 65535 f 
57 1
0000088682 00000 n 
221 7
0000088804 00000 n 
0000088450 00000 n 
0000054970 00000 n 
0000088289 00000 n 
0000054837 00000 n 
0000088111 00000 n 
0000088211 00000 n 
trailer
<</Size 228/Root 221 0 R/Info 222 0 R/ID [<e8f997fdc4d9ee619c59add6882586d8><d13406b4c1e0cb3de6c1e8dd21d6be13>]/Prev 50291>>
startxref
89038
%%EOF
```

You see the end-of-file marker (`%%EOF`) preceded with the starting positing of the cross-reference table (`startxref`, in this case the `xref` table starts at position 89038).

The cross-reference table defines the byte offsets of every object inside the PDF. In PDF versions prior to PDF 1.5, the Cross-reference table is added in plain text, and each byte offset is defined using ten digits. Hence the size of a file will be limited to 10 to the tenth bytes (approximately 10 gigabytes).

The maximum size of a PDF with a version older than PDF 1.5 is about 10 gigabytes.

Starting with PDF 1.5, you can also have this:

```
34 0 obj
<</Length 52/Filter/FlateDecode/Size 35/Root 8 0 R/Info 6 0 R/ID [<4dc91a1875a6d707aec203bb021c93a0><b6fc5ae423a75860537207ff441de268>]/W[1 2 2]/Type/XRef/Index[0 2 6 1 8 2 28 7]/Prev 116>>stream
xœc``øÿŸq‘-ãB9 ±Şš‰A™QÈ]Pá%AXŒ ‚‰¤ =› ñ
endstream
endobj
startxref
45383
%%EOF
```

We still have the end-of-file marker, and we still point to the starting point of the cross-reference table, but the entries of the cross-reference table are no longer visible in clear text. They are compressed: ``` xœc``øÿŸq‘-ãB9 ±Şš‰A™QÈ]Pá%AXŒ ‚‰¤ =› ñ ```

This allows you to create files with a file size higher than 10 gigabytes. All of this is explained in ISO 32000-1 and ISO 32000-2.

This is a screen shot of the PDF specification:

[image]

If you have software that digitally signs documents, but only supports the format that predates PDF 1.5, I would seriously question whether that software supports digital signatures that meet today's standards. I recently saw a project where a developer still used SHA-1 as the hashing algorithm. Fortunately, I was able to explain that this was wrong by referring him to a [blog about SHA-1](https://itextpdf.com/ja/blog/are-pdf-signatures-shattered), otherwise he'd probably have been fired if his employer found out (or sued if his customer discovered that he was paying for signatures that are no longer considered being safe).